# Unable to connect to Salesforce on Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to connect to my Salesforce QA environment on Azure Data Factory but am not having any success even though I entered my username, password, and my security token after resetting it under Salesforce QA>Settings>My Personal Information>Reset My Security Token. Am I missing something?

I tried putting some environment urls but it didn't work so I removed it. Not sure what else I can do at this point... Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind this is resolved! I set the environment url to https://test.salesforce.com and it worked. :)